# How do you stop WP from stripping <p> code?

Tags: editor

I can't stand Gutenberg and use the disable Gutenberg plugin.
But... Wordpress is stripping the

tags. How do I STOP this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the wpautop function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

Comment: Hello & thank you for your answer! Could you [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/377047/edit) using the [edit link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/377047/edit) and maybe add in an example of how OP could implement this? Link only answers are usually discouraged. For more information please check out [our help docs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)